# Access only the First Object from a JSON Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

This is my json from the code below:

```
"ict":[
   {
      "module1":{
         "1":[
            "OS",
            "Operating system"
         ],
         "2":[
            "CA",
            "Computer Application"
         ],
         "3":[
            "CM",
            "Computational Mathematics"
         ],
         "4":[
            "CA",
            "Computer Application"
         ],
         "5":[
            "Programming",
            "Structured Programming"
         ]
      },
```

I want to access this part

```
"1":["OS","Operating system"]
```

but get the string `"OS"` without fetching the whole string.

When I run my java code which is this:

```
private void addItemsFromJSON() {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(readJSONDataFromFile());
        JSONArray coursea = jsonObject.getJSONArray("ict");

         for (int i = 0; i < coursea.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject cc = coursea.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject contact = cc.getJSONObject("module1");
                courses.add(new course(contact.getString("1"),"",String.valueOf(content.get(ran.nextInt(content.size())))));

            }




    } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "addItemsFromJSON: 777", e);
    }
}
```

The output that I get is `["OS", "Operating system"]`

How can I retrieve only the first object from a json key array with multiple values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data at "1" refers to another `JSONArray`, so to get the first item in the array you would do something like this:

```
JSONArray array = contact.getJSONArray("1");
array.getString(0);
```

---

In JSON objects are denoted using `{}` and arrays with `[]`. If you're trying to access a specific value in your JSON object then it's really just a case of following the path to it, through the arrays and objects.